# Unrecognized expression without trace in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixitup

i upgraded my version of jQuery and after i fixed all the errors that came it brought up i am now stack with this:

[image: my console output]

IT belongs to a pretty big script, so i cannot even find where the error is, let alone fix it.

Is there any way to track it better? i replaced my jQuery with unminified version, and everything else is unminified as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So a bad selector.

Comment: Sizzle is the selector engine that jQuery uses. You must be selecting `$('.' + someVariable)` where `someVariable` is `null` or an empty string. You can reproduce this by running: `$('.')`

Comment: Thanks guys, found it by digging the whole codebase. I had a $_GET var paired with my selector and if it wasnt set it gave me that error. Fixed it with an if that checks if the value exists before echoeing the selector.